# jQuery AJAX unexpected `undefined` result (Valid JSON)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a PhoneGap / jQuery Mobile app that I am developing. I am getting some strange results on script that I have used before.

```
$.ajax({type: "GET",
            url: "http://****.net/****/GetMembers.php",
            data: {get_param: "Member"},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                    $("#members-content").append("<li><a id='members-a-" + element.ID + "' data-id='" + element.ID + "' href='#member-details'><img src='" + element.ImgURL + "' /><h3>" + element.Name + "</h3></a></li>");
                    $("#members-a-" + element.ID).bind('click', function () {Members.MemberID = $(this).attr('data-id'); MemberDetails.Load(); });
                    $("#members-content").listview("refresh");
                    });
           }
    });
```

JSON returned from webservice:

> [{"Member":{"ID":1,"Name":"Member 1","ImgURL":null}},{"Member":{"ID":2,"Name":"Member 2","ImgURL":null}},{"Member":{"ID":3,"Name":"Member 3","ImgURL":null}},{"Member":{"ID":4,"Name":"Member 4","ImgURL":null}}]

In my `#members-content` list I am getting `undefined` for the `<h3>` name element.

Comment: Before you start the loop in success function , use this: data=data[0], and then continue the loop.

Comment: It seems like it would be element.Member.ID, element.Member.Name, etc.  Have you tried breaking this in Firebug or some other JavaScript debugger and seeing if you can fiddle with the element?

Comment: data=data[0] would mean: data={"Member":{"ID":1,"Name":"Member 1","ImgURL":null}},{"Member":{"ID":2,"Name":"Member 2","ImgURL":null}},{"Member":{"ID":3,"Name":"Member 3","ImgURL":null}},{"Member":{"ID":4,"Name":"Member 4","ImgURL":null}}

Comment: @user2008945 No it wouldn't. data[0] would just be `{"Member":{"ID":1,"Name":"Member 1","ImgURL":null}}`

Comment: Yah.. you are right.. seems like I need to get my fundamentals cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a double-nested object there. You should be using

```
element.Member.ImgURL
```

e.g. look at the json:

```
[
    {   <--element in your .each() loop
       "Member": {
           "ID":1,
           "Name":"Member 1",
           "ImgURL":null
       }
    },
    { etc...
```

Comment: I thought that using `data: {get_param:"Member"}` would make the `Member` object the root, therefore only needing `element.ID` to get my data. So this is an incorrect assumption and I should drill down through the member object anyways.

Comment: that's only for what you're sending to the server. I have no idea how this server works, but things don't generally have to come back in the same format you sent it.

Answer (score 1):

Each element has a Member. So:

```
element.ID
```

Should be:

```
element.Member.ID
```

Same goes for ImgURL and Name

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: [find the two in fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ChkfL/)

Either loop through as you are currently doing but with one change:

This has to be like this `element.Member.Name`

or loop through it once again like this:

```
$.each(data, function (index, element) {
   $.each(element, function (index, e) {
    console.log(e.Name); // <----here you will get the correct response
   });
});
```